# How to get no expiry refresh token in Azure B2C flow in React

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-ad-b2c, implicit-grant

I'm trying to achieve a scenario where having a no expiry refresh token in my react application so users don't need to keep re-login every 24 hrs. But in the current implementation with the MSAL js library, it is only allowing to use of the **Authorization code flow** and it is not allowing to have no expiry tokes as per this documentation[1][2].

Is there any way we can use **Azure AD B2C** with no expiry refresh token? using SPA app with MSAL or any other react OIDC library

Highly appreciate Microsoft azure b2c experts insights on this

Thanks

[1]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-third-party-cookies-spas#security-implications-of-refresh-tokens-in-the-browser

[2]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-tokens?pivots=b2c-user-flow#token-lifetime-behavior

Answer (score 2):

As the docs imply, the RT is 24hours fixed for SPA apps.

You can use Keep Me Signed In as a way to get long lived sessions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-user-flow#enable-keep-me-signed-in-kmsi

Answer (score 1):

As per the document SPAs will be issued tokens valid for only 24 hours. Single-page applications using the authorization code flow with PKCE always have a refresh token lifetime of 24 hours and for the other apps we do not experience this limitation.

there is no other way to set the no expiry refresh token.